# Кодировка БД и сайта

Tags: php, sql, unicode

Знаю что вопросов таких была уйма, но гуляя на стаке не нашел решение своей проблемы, пожалуйста простите. 
Из бд , и в бд кирилица попадает как всякие символы, у всех файлов и у всех таблиц и бд кодировка одна и та же utf8_general_ci Только вот "Сопоставление кодировки соединения " в phpmyadmin другая, но я его и изменить не могу. 
Хостинг от рег.ру, помогите с проблемой) 
И дело точно в бд , так как на странице есть статичные тексты на кирилице, и все нормально отображается, но как только с бд, так символы.

Comment: А зачем unicode? почему не UTF8? utf8_general_ci

Comment: Поправил пост, извините. utf8_general_ci

Comment: А тех поддержка то что отвечает?

Comment: Им пока не писал, думал что ошибка может быть с моей стороны.

Comment: В качестве самой первой меры попробуйте применить `SET NAMES 'utf8'` при открытии соединения.

Comment: Его нужно в бд SQL юзануть?

Comment: Его нужно использовать как самый первый запрос соединения. Либо указать в свойствах соединения как дополнительную инит-команду. Добавьте в вопрос вывод запроса `show variables like "col%";`.

Comment: Я больше чем уверен что проблема только с вашей стороны. Сколько помню себя, всегда использовал данный хостинг, никогда проблем с кодировкой не было. Проверяйте php файлы, проверяйте html файлы на кодировку, проверяйте бд на utf8. Покажите ваш php файл, html файл (заголовки). Проверьте в какой кодировке вы сохраняете файл, разные текстовые редакторы могут сохранять по разному.

Comment: Akina, честно сказать не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: Изменил кодировку файлов, теперь на странице все нормально, но все ровно в бд сохраняется как символы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хочу помочь всем , кто в дальнейшем столкнется с такой же проблемой, пишите поддержке сайта, они умеют исправлять кодировку, если конечно же до того как поставить ваш сайт на их хостинг у вас все работало.